# Type mismatch with generic parameter

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to run the following code, but I'm getting the following compiler error: `Error:(12, 9) Type mismatch: inferred type is Child but Parent<Any> was expected`.

```
abstract class Parent<T> {
    abstract fun hi()
}
class Child: Parent<String>() {
    override fun hi() {
        println("Hi from child")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!")
    test(Child())
}

fun test(parent: Parent<Any>) {
    parent.hi()
}
```

But the Java's equivalent, works as expected:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(new Child());
    }

    public static void test(Parent object) {
        object.hi();
    }
}

abstract class Parent<T> {
    public abstract void hi();
}

class Child extends Parent<String> {

    public void hi() {
        System.out.println("Hi from child");
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the Kotlin code?

Comment: Your Java code appears to be using raw types: `public static void test(Parent object)`. That might be a factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `Parent<String>` to be a subtype of `Parent<Any>`. Since `String` is a subtype of `Any`, what you're looking for is called covariance. You can mark the type parameter of `Parent` to behave this way with the `out` keyword:

```
abstract class Parent<out T> {
    abstract fun hi()
}
```

See more about variance in the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance).

---

As for why the Java example works, @Carcigenicate already mentioned in the comment above that you're using raw types there, e.g. the `parent` parameter of your `test` function doesn't have a type parameter at all. You can achieve something similar with a [star projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) in Kotlin, if you really have to:

```
fun test(parent: Parent<*>) {
    parent.hi()
}
```